# Problems with COUNT.IF function in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am probably doing something wrong, but what I want to do is check for the word "Yes" in a specific range. But even when I put 'Yes' in this range, it keeps returning a value of 0. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: The result is 0 because there is nothing to sum ... try using AANTAL.ALS (COUNTIF) instead

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below formula
=countif($K:$K,"YES")

This will count cells with yes

[image]

Let me know if you need help

Thank you

regards
Supreeth